# Open Source Database with encryption at rest and auditing functionaility

Tags: database, postgresql, open-source

The organisation I work at usually uses Oracle or SQL Server for our databases.  However we have a requirement to create only a small database, but the small amount of data it will hold is highly sensitive (IL3).

It has been specified that we need to encrypt the data 'at rest' and provide auditing of anyone looking at records in the database.

We know that SQL Server and Oracle can do that.  But as this server will not be able to utilize existing licenses, an expensive edition of the database would be required to provide the functionality that is required.  Thus we are considering alternatives with lower or no licensing costs.

We need to also be able to use a connector from Entity Framework Connector.

Are there any open source databases that can deliver that functionality?
Can Postgresql provide that functionality?

Thanks,
DavidC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption is straightforward enough - just set up an encrypted partition and keep your data on there. That keeps the encryption out of reach of the RDBMS altogether.

For the auditing, it depends how strict you need to be. There's no way to keep someone with full superuser access from fiddling with logs etc.

However, you could log all queries and copy logs to a different machine (presumably keeping the logs on an encrypted partition too).

For routine access direct all access through custom functions that log access along with user details.